# libreoffice base macro parametric open close get current form name

Tags: macros, libreoffice

libreoffice Base 4.3.3.2
Opening a Form page by name and then close the current page form like this work:

```
oForm = ThisDatabaseDocument.FormDocuments.getByName("SecondForm") 
oForm.Open 
oFormC = ThisDatabaseDocument.FormDocuments.getByName("CurrentForm") 
oFormC.Close
```

but is there a way to close oFormC without writing by hand his name?

trying with:

```
    oFormC = Event.Source.Model.Parent
    oFormC  = ThisDatabaseDocument.FormDocuments.getByName(Event.Source.Model.Parent) 
oFormC = getParent()
```

return an error of var not set

Can't find any help in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term 'form' in LibreOffice/OpenOffice is confusing because it refers both to the entire document (typically a Writer file) and also to each group of form controls inside that document.  So each form document can have many forms (meaning a group of controls) inside it, and forms (groups of controls) can have sub-forms.

This code gets a form document (a Writer file embedded inside a Base file):

`oDoc = ThisDatabaseDocument.FormDocuments.getByName("SecondForm")`

This code gets the form that is a group of controls and that contains the control which triggered the macro: `oForm = Event.Source.Model.Parent`
Another way to get a group of controls inside the form document in which the macro was triggered: `oForm = ThisComponent.drawpage.forms.MainForm`

Replace "MainForm" with your actual form name - form here meaning a group of controls.  You can see the names of forms and subforms that are inside a form document by opening the Form Navigator window.  Make sure the toolbar Form Design is visible; the Form Navigator icon is the sixth from the left or top, looks like a rectangle with a compass in the upper right corner.

You may have guessed from the previous code how to close the document that is active when the macro is triggered:

`ThisComponent.close`